# Is there a way to set a fullscreen app to always be on Desktop 1?

Tags: macos, spotify, mission-control

When I enter fullscreen on spotify, Mac OS automatically creates a new space on the right side of my desktop screens. I'd like to always have it open into the desktop beside the "Dashboard" desktop. Is this possible?

[image: Mission control screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Fullscreen apps cannot be forced to anywhere except "right-most".

You can achieve similar by setting it to Maximised instead of fullscreen, then you can lock it to any Space by right clicking the dock icon & setting Options > This Desktop.